# SPD workflows triggered from console application failed to send email

Tags: sharepoint-designer, workflow

I have SPD workflow on list which gets triggered from console application running on SharePoint Server.

Workflow is very simple, it just checks if date from one field in the list is today's date or older and sends email to about it to one email address.

It was working as expected and it suddenly stopped working. Workflow is failing at the step of sending an email and goes on to Cancelled status.

If I trigger workflow manually from SharePoint user interface it will run without any issue.

Any help on this is much appreciated.

Comment: make sure you are not updating item from an Admin account,

Comment: @Gaurravs, Workflow does not update any field value, it just reads the value to match condition.

Comment: I am not saying about Workflow, It Is for console application code I am talking about

Comment: @Gaurravs, console application just calls StartWorkflow on each item in the list to trigger associated workflow, so it does not update any value. Also, I have verified that if I do not use Send Email step, it works correctly and logs information in the history list.